# OpenCV 2.4.3 PCA class - when number of samples is less than number of dimensions

Tags: opencv, pca

I'm trying to use the PCA class in OpenCv to perform the principal component analysis operation in my C++ application . I'm new to OpenCV and I'm having a problem So I wish if someone could help.

I'm trying a demo Example on both Matlab and the PCA class to check the answers
when I'm using 2*10 data array, and the parameter `(CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL)`, here I'm having two dimensions so I'm expecting to have 2 Eigenvectors each has 2 elements, and this worked fine as expected with the same results as Matlab.

But while using 10*2 data array (generally when number of samples is less than number of dimension), I get (2*10) array of eiegnvectors. I.e: 10 eigenvectors with 2 elements each. This is not expected and it's not the result given by Matlab (Matlab give 10*10 matrix of eigenvectors).

I don't know why I'm having those results and due this I can't project the Data on principal components in my application, any help?

P.S : The code I used :

```
Mat Mean ;
Mat H(10, 2, CV_32F); // then the matrix is filled by data
    PCA pca(H,Mean,CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL,0) ;
pca.operator()(H,Mean,CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL,0) ;
    cout<<pca.eigenvectors.rows // gives 2 instead of 10
    cout<<pca.eigenvectors.cols // gives 10
```

Comment: Could you post the C++ code you're using?

Comment: maybe it's a question about CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL vs CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW here ? eg. i've been successfully using opencv's pca for face detection with rows as the num of images, and cols as the total numelements per image, flattened to a 1d array.

Comment: The code :
        Mat Mean ;
 Mat H(2, 10, CV_32F); // then the matrix is filled by data
        PCA pca(H,Mean,CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL,0) ;
 pca.operator()(H,Mean,CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL,0) ;
cout<<pca.eigenvectors.rows // gives 2
cout<<pca.eigenvectors.cols // gives 2 ,and this is fine
the other case :


Mat Mean ;
 Mat H(10, 2, CV_32F); // then the matrix is filled by data
        PCA pca(H,Mean,CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL,0) ;
 pca.operator()(H,Mean,CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL,0) ;
        cout<<pca.eigenvectors.rows // gives 2 instead of 10
        cout<<pca.eigenvectors.cols // gives 10 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'd state it as follows:

**If the number of samples is less than the data dimension then the number of retained components will be clamped at the number of samples.**

We did 3x3 PCA for mechanics subject at uni, also some non-linear control algorithms used similar approaches - my memory is foggy, but it may have something to do with assumptions regarding psuedo-inverses and non-square matrices...

Once you delve into the theory - websearch 'pca with less samples than dimensions' - it gets messy fast!