# Dimension reduction with PCA in OpenCV, wrong dimensions of eigenvectors

Tags: c++, opencv, pca

I am not sure if this problem is already on stackoverflow, but I could not find it so i decided to open a new question. I am trying to reduce the dimension of a feature Matrix. I have 58 features and 30 instances / measurements. I want to reduce the number of features to 40. But there seems to be a problem with my matrices' dimensions.

- featureMatrix_cv is my feature matrix with 30 rows and 58 columns

  ```
  PCA pca_analysis(featureMatrix_cv, cv::Mat(), cv::PCA::DATA_AS_ROW, 40);

  cv::Mat neu = pca_analysis.project(featureMatrix_cv.row(0));
  ```
- The first problem is, `pca_analysis.eigenvectors` has the wrong dimensions I think (30 rows and 58 columns). I read in several tutorial, that i should get N N-dimensional eigenvectors, where N is the number of features (here 58). Same problem for `pca_analysis.eigenvalues` (30 rows and 1 column), It should heave the size (58, 1).
- In the second line, I tried to project the first instance into the new dimension space, but this isn't working because instead of 40 values, `pca_analysis.project` returns a matrix with 30 values. I read in a tutorial that the projected vector/matix should have 40 values, that is the dimension of the feature space.

Is there anybody that could help me or had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after finding [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283338/opencv-2-4-3-pca-class-when-number-of-samples-is-less-than-number-of-dimension), I know now what the problem was: I need more instances than features! If I have 58 features, I just need at least 58 samples. This is not a problem for me, because I have enough data, I was just using 30 samples all the time for testing.